# pass range of dates on selecting two dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Jquery Datepicker where i need to select a date range, like the start date and end date. 
Currently I am passing (individual) selected date on a click of a button. I need some understanding how can i pass the date range.

**Jquery Calender (Datepicker)**

```
function showSelectDatesFromCalendar() {
    $('#selectDates').datepick({minDate: new Date(1990, 1 - 1, 1),maxDate: new Date(), defaultDate: new Date(), monthsToShow:[1,3],monthsToStep:3, multiSelect:999,dateFormat:'mm/dd/yyyy'
        ,changeMonth:false, showSpeed:'#fast'});
}
```

1) If I select 1 dec and 30 dec, 1 dec is start date, 30 dec is end date. then
it should pass all the dates in between the start and end date.

How can i achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DatePicker setting

Check for "**rangeSelectSet**" and set it to **"true"** to allow the selection of a date range in the datepicker.

The first selected date is the start of the range and the second selected date is the end of the range. You can Set to **"false"** to select a single date.

[reference](http://keith-wood.name/datepickRef.html)

```
function showSelectDatesFromCalendar() {
    $('#selectDates').datepick({minDate: new Date(1990, 1 - 1, 1),maxDate: new Date(), defaultDate: new Date(), monthsToShow:[1,3],monthsToStep:3, multiSelect:999,dateFormat:'mm/dd/yyyy'
        ,changeMonth:false, showSpeed:'#fast', rangeSelect:true,});
}
```

Check the Modified code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with callbacks to manually assign / change things.

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
     //  your modification here.
   }
});
```

See the `Events` tab on http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

EDIT: See [Proper way to add a callback to jQuery DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101287/proper-way-to-add-a-callback-to-jquery-datepicker), they are providing large examples for things.

Comment: http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html
"Unlimited" dates: tab
I am exactly using the same Jquery library. Rather than selecting multiple dates, i would like to chose only start and end date and every dates in between should automatically be selected.