# Datepicker is lost after a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jsf-2.2

I've got this code to generate my datepicker:

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                showOn : 'button',
                buttonImage : '../resources/images/calendar.png',
                buttonImageOnly : true,
                buttonText : 'Pick a date',
                onSelect : function() {
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Every time there is a postback, I loose all my calendars.

I am working with JAVA and not .net. How can I do to resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: show the html code of your .datepicker

Comment: When you say postback , what java framework are you using ?

Comment: I use the JSF Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved to use this workaround; I changed my code like this:

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@all">
```

Instead of:

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form">
```

This way, all the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an object literal that contains the extensions as below, more you can find on [Proper way to add a callback to jQuery DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101287/proper-way-to-add-a-callback-to-jquery-datepicker)

```
(function($){
    var datepickerExtensions = {
        _oldAdjustDate: $.datepicker._adjustDate,
        _adjustDate: function(id, offset, period) { 
            var target = $(id);
            var inst = this._getInst(target[0]);
            var afterAdjustDate = this._get(inst, 'afterAdjustDate');
            this._oldAdjustDate(id, offset, period);
            if(afterAdjustDate && typeof afterAdjustDate === 'function'){
                afterAdjustDate(id, offset, period);
            }
        }
    }
    $.extend($.datepicker, datepickerExtensions);
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: oh ok, what error you are getting ? try                                                       **function pageLoad() { }**

Comment: There is no error... I put an alert in the script. It's called when I first load my page, but it's not when it's loaded with postbacks.

Comment: It's just small parts of my page that are reloaded, and not the entire page. I don't how to say to relaod the javascript code every time there is a postback.