# how to write a callback function, after the datapicker date selection?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datapicker

I am using `datapicker` on a `field` to pop out `calender`. after the selection of date by using this `datapicker` i want to execute a `callback` function, in that function i want to `set` this `selected date` `value` to `another` field.

this is my currrent code

```
<%= text_field_tag "from_date",Date.today.beginning_of_month.strftime("%d-%b-%Y") , :class=>"form-control from_picker", :id => "start",'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker',:placeholder =>"From" %>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = "dd-M-yyyy";

  $(document).on("focus", "[data-behaviour~='datepicker']", function(e){
    $(this).datepicker({"autoclose": true,
                         onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                           alert(selectedDate);
                           var from_picker = $(".from_picker").val();
                           $("#d_start").val(from_picker.toString());
                         }
    });
  });
</script>


<%= text_field_tag "set_date",Date.today.beginning_of_month.strftime("%d-%b-%Y") , :class=>"form-control", :id => "d_start",'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker',:placeholder =>"From" %>
```

the datapicker is working fine. am able to select the date. but the callback is not getting executed, because of that i am unable set this value to other field.

Comment: You did not close the script tag, maybe the problem is there ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101287/proper-way-to-add-a-callback-to-jquery-datepicker

Comment: i tried that. that is also not working.